# PhpStorm not working with Xdebug 3: configured but PhpStorm not detecting Xdebug

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, phpstorm, xdebug

I have installed PhpStorm 2020.3.1 and installed latest Xdebug, here is my phpinfo output:

[image: phpinfo output]

and my php.ini is:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=true
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 3600
xdebug.client_host=localhost
xdebug.client_port = 9100
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.mode = debug
```

And here is my PhpStorm configuration:

[image: phpstorm_configuration]

My problem is when I click the button in the top left of PhpStorm to listen to Xdebug and use Postman to send request I get nothing, PhpStorm is not detecting the Xdebug.

How to solve this? Is my configuration correct?

Comment: 1) When posting phpinfo, you better ALSO show the whole Xdebug section of that (will be later down) -- it shows actual/live Xdebug settings. 2) PhpStorm screenshot -- that's the WRONG settings screen. Change that port back to `63342` or whatever was there and restart IDE. It has nothing to do with Xdebug or PHP. Then go back to the Settings screen and just type `xdebug` in the search box -- it will show a more appropriate screens (`Languages & Framework | PHP | Debug`).